# Tapping on the circular icon button gets converted to square in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I added circular buttons in my flutter mobile app but when I tap or click on them, those buttons gets converted to square buttons. I am adding my code below, please let me know what I am doing wrong, your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks,

```
child: Material(
            color: Colors.black,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            child: Center(
              child: Ink(
                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white12,
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  onPressed: () {
                    bool isGR = Game.of(context).isGameRunning();
                    if (isGR) {
                      Game.of(context).pause();
                    }
                    TapboxA.of(context).backToSplash();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I am adding images as well below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried on my end but not reproducible

Comment: I tried this on Android Studio and Samsung Phone... Its reproducible on both.

Comment: I check on the Samsung phone. It shows circular

Comment: Yes, But when you Tap on those buttons.. or long press those buttons it becomes Square.

Comment: I tried both image background only shows circular

Comment: Can you just comment code inside of onPressed() {}, then check, Let me know if it changes behavior or not

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

I tested it on Dart Pad and it works fine, don't know why its breaking on my side.. let me figure it out.